# Saving Python dictionary to netCDF4 file

Tags: python, dictionary, hdf5, netcdf

I am learning to use Python module for netCDF4 (and netCDF4 in general). Using HDF5 file format, there is a natural way to translate Python dictionaries to HDF5 data structure - using group's attributes:

```
parameters = {'a':1.0, 'b':2.0, 'c':3.0}
f = h5py.File("test.hdf5",'w')
hdf_parms = f.create_group("parameters")
for k,v in parameters.items():
        hdf_parms.attrs[k]=v
```

What is the smart netCDF4 way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
parameters = {'a':1.0, 'b':2.0, 'c':3.0}
f = netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc', 'w')
parms = f.createGroup('parameters')
for k,v in parameters.items():
    setattr(parms, k, v)
```