# save a netsted dictionary to hdf or netCDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, netcdf, hdf

Generally, it is straightforward to save a dictionary to hdf or netCDF. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434723/saving-python-dictionary-to-netcdf4-file).
But how to deal with the nested dictionaries. For example following dictionary:

```
test = {'temp': {'unit': 'K', 'data': [273.,298.,315.]}, 'press': {'unit': 'hPa', 'data': [800.,900.,1000.]}}
```

Please note that nesting can go until several levels. So I need subgroups within groups of netCDF or hdf

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out the answer

import numpy as np
import h5py

```
def dict2hdf5(filename, dic):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as h5file:
        recursive_dict2hdf5(h5file, '/', dic)


def recursive_dict2hdf5(h5file, path, dic):
    for key, item in dic.items():
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            key = str(key)
        if isinstance(item, (np.ndarray, np.int64, np.float64, str, bytes)):
            h5file[path + key] = item
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            h5file[path + key] = np.array(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            recursive_dict2hdf5(h5file, path + key + '/',
                                item)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Cannot save %s type' % type(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this function can help. I have customised it here for your example, but it would work better if you can provide a dictionary of attributes, and make it work similar to 'data'. I am using xarray to demonstrate how to get a dataset variable, but you can transfer the idea to your tool of choice.

```
import xarray as xr

def create_variable(dataset, var, test, dimensions):

    data = test[var]['data'] 
    attrs = {'unit':test[var]['unit']} 


    v = xr.Variable(dimensions, data, attrs=attrs)
    dataset[var] = v

    return var
```

Comment: The issue is that the dictionary can be nested at several levels. Depending on the application, the number if bests may vary.